# Add computed JSON columns in Serilog Sinks.MSSqlServer

Tags: c#, serilog

Is it possible to add computed JSON columns based on Serilogs LogEvent table with the fluent configuration?

What I'm after is the fluent API to generate:

```
ALTER TABLE [APPLICATION_LOG]
ADD CorrelationId AS JSON_VALUE([LogEvent], '$.Properties.CorrelationId') PERSISTED;
```

What I have now:

```
var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
columnOptions.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent); // swap xml column for JSON log events
columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
columnOptions.AdditionalColumns = new List<SqlColumn>
{
   new() { ColumnName = "CorrelationId", ...? }
};
```